# Как добавить иконку *.exe файлу в CLion C++

Tags: c++, exe, clion, icon, jetbrains

Как добавить иконку *.exe файлу в CLion C++?
Пробовал создать файл ресурсов, но что-то не знаю, как прикрутить его в CLion'е...подскажите, пожалуйста, может, в настройках проекта где-то есть? В гугле вообще не нашёл..

Comment: Какой у вас компилятор?

Comment: mingw32 (g++) стандартный

Comment: [windres](https://linux.die.net/man/1/i686-pc-mingw32-windres) ну и ответ на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/708382/9630063), ну и для [cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543845/9630063)